# Given ratio of consecutive numbers to arrive at fraction of total number

Tags: probability, exponential-function, fractions, exponential-distribution

Given

The ratio of number of oscillators in their (n+1)th quantum state of excitation to the number in their nth quantum state is
$$N_n+1/N_n = \exp(-\hbar\omega/K_bT)$$

Thus the fraction of the total number of oscillators in the nth quantum state is
$$ \frac{N_n}{\sum_{s=0}^\infty N_s}=\frac{\exp(-n\hbar\omega/K_bT)}{\sum_{s=0}^\infty \exp(-s\hbar\omega/K_bT)}$$
Can someone explain the math behind how to arrive at equation 2 from equation 1

Comment: Is that ratio supposed to be $$\frac{N_{n+1}}{N_n}?$$

Comment: And if saulspatz' suspicion is correct (it most likely is), then we can write $\exp(-\hbar\omega/K_bT) = c$ and since $N_{n+1}/N_n = c \implies N_n=c^nN_0$ is geometric, it's easy to see that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ratio is in fact $N_{n+1}/N_n$, which completely makes sense given OP's first sentence, we can write $\exp(-\hbar\omega/K_bT) = c$ and we know that $N_{n+1}/N_n = c \implies N_n=c^nN_0$. Thus we trivially obtain:
$$ \require{cancel}
\frac{N_n}{\sum_{s=0}^\infty N_s}
=\frac{c^{n}\cancel{N_0}}{\sum_{s=0}^\infty c^{s}\cancel{N_0}}
=\frac{c^{n}}{\sum_{s=0}^\infty c^{s}}
=\frac{\exp(-\hbar\omega/K_bT)^{n}}{\sum_{s=0}^\infty \exp(-\hbar\omega/K_bT)^{s}}
=\frac{\exp(-n\hbar\omega/K_bT)}{\sum_{s=0}^\infty \exp(-s\hbar\omega/K_bT)} $$